# How do you coreference a possesive pronouns with an x-bar tree?

Tags: syntax, syntax-trees, pronouns, chomsky, x-bar-theory

Following Chomsky's linguistic theory (The Minimalist Program), r-expressions must be free, where free means that nothing should c-command it such that the indices have a non null intersection (if I have understood correctly).

Here is an example:

In the sentence 'His boss criticised John' where his and John are coreferenced, is John free or not? He does not c-command John, but the possesive does. So what exactly is coreferenced in this tree with John, he or (pos).

(I hope the tree is correct! If the DP His Boss was actually an NP with head boss, I think the problem would be solved?)

[image: This is what I think the x-bar tree for 'His boss criticised John]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example, whether *His boss* is analysed as a DP or as an NP with the noun *boss* as head, the possessive *his* does **not** c-command *John* (you are mistaken in this respect), which, as a consequence, is 'free' and satisfies Principle C of Binding Theory, as all r-expressions must. What Principle C says is only that r-expressions must **not** be **c-commanded** (and therefore automatically 'bound') by any co-referential expression, be it in the same 'binding domain' (the clause, in this case) or in a higher one, but that does **not** block co-reference between *his* and *John*: as *his* does **not** c-command *John*, it cannot bind it either (= make *John* **obligatorily** co-referential with it). Principle C **allows** *his* and *John* to **not** be co-referential; it by no means forces then to be **non**-coreferential, a very different claim. In consequence, in your example the possessive *his* **may** indeed refer to the same individual as the noun *John* does (= John, in that case), but it need **not**; it may also refer to any other male individual. The only r-expression that does c-command *John* in your example is *His boss*, but *His boss* cannot possibly be interpreted as referring to the same individual *John* does; if it could, the r-expression *John* would automatically be 'bound', in violation of Principle C of Binding Theory, and to save the sentence it would be necessary to replace it with the matching reflexive *himself*, according to Principle A.